# Any ZMQ bindings for Erlang on Windows?

Tags: erlang, zeromq

Is it possible to use Erlang with ZMQ on Windows? I have tried to use `erlzmq2`, but `rebar` fails to compile it with cryptic linker errors. Of course i can invest some time and investigate makefiles, but maybe other way exists?

**Update**

Whose who are interested in compilation errors can download latest erlang for windows and try to build erlzmq2 (Visual Studio 2012 compiler, `msys` `sh` and `make`). Error looks like:

```
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wl,-DLL,-IMPLIB:.libs
\zmq.dll.lib'
Makefile:541: recipe for target 'libzmq.la' failed
make[3]: *** [libzmq.la] Error 2
```

Please note that other erlang libs are compiling with this setup without any problems.

Comment: Your question should include the errors you're seeing.

Comment: Just finished native Erlang implementation: https://github.com/chovencorp/erlangzmq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in compiling ZeroMQ for Windows. You haven't actually gotten to any Erlang yet. Here are some of the clues that tell you this:

> Makefile:541: recipe for target 'libzmq.la' failed

This line says there's a problem on line 541 of the Makefile. But in [erlzmq2](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2), you can see that neither [the main Makefile](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2/blob/master/Makefile) nor the [c_src Makefile](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2/blob/master/c_src/Makefile) (which is what would build libzmq.la) has anything close to that many lines.

> make[3](https://github.com/zeromq/erlzmq2/blob/master/c_src/Makefile): *** [libzmq.la] Error 2

The `[3]` means that you're 3 invocations deep into Make. Specifically, you started at the top-level Makefile, which called Rebar, which ran `make -C c_src`, which downloads ZeroMQ version 3.2.2 and tries to do a `./configure && make`

To fix this Unix-style, go into the `deps` directory of erlzmq2 and figure out how to correctly compile ZeroMQ. Hopefully, you will just need to pass some arguments to `configure`. Then you can edit `c_src/Makefile` and set `ZMQ_FLAGS` to whatever you had to do for configure, clean, and make.

To fix it more Windows-style, follow the Windows build instructions for ZeroMQ. Put the compiled libzmq under deps and just edit the c_src Makefile to a no-op.

Finally, if you don't actually need to run this code on Windows, but are just using Windows as your development environment, I think you'll have the easiest time by running the build inside a Linux VM (not a hard thing at all with tools like Vagrant). Sorry, but Unix is the real system for this stuff; Windows support is an afterthought.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As i mentioned in my question, i can tinker with makefiles, but was hoping that someone already done that or it's possible to use already compiled version.